# calculating from each line of an array using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I'm very new to c# and programming in general. I'm having some issues trying to get this program to work.

I've to input 5 names from a text file, add 5 scores to each name, remove the max and min score for each name, and then display the winner.  What I have done so far only seems to be adding up all the scores.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Diving_Championship
{
   class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            

        string[] divers = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\1 -C# Programming\Coursework\DiverName.txt");          
        string DiverScore;
        int score = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 10;
        int Totalscore = 0;
        int[] Finalscore = new int[5];
        int max1 = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DiverScore = divers[i];

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Score between 0 and 10 for {0}", DiverScore);
                score = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

                while (score < 0 || score > 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Score Is Invalid, Please Re-Enter a score between 0 and 10");
                    score = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                if (score > max)
                {
                    max = score;
                }
                if (score < min)
                {
                    min = score;
                }

                Totalscore += score;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Finalscore[i] = Totalscore - max - min;

            if (Finalscore[0] > max1)
            {
                max1 = Finalscore[0];
            }

            if (Finalscore[1] > max1)
            {
                max1 = Finalscore[1];
            }

            if (Finalscore[2] > max1)
            {
                max1 = Finalscore[2];
            }

            if (Finalscore[3] > max1)
            {
                max1 = Finalscore[3];
            }

            if (Finalscore[4] > max1)
            {
                max1 = Finalscore[4];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("the max score is {0}", max1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem a little bit? What variable has the wrong value at the end, why is wrong, what do you expect instead? Provide a small sample. Why do you use nested loops at all instead of `for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)`?

Comment: max1 is the wrong variable at the end, I use a nested loop so that it adds a score to each name on each line of the "divers[]" array, if I do (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) then I get an exception error

Comment: What's the exception error you are getting? Please post it here, we can't help you without you posting the required information..

Comment: To help figure out what your program is doing when it runs you could put some print statements at places where you expect something to happen - then examine the output and see if it did what you expected. It's a good way to debug a program as a beginner. You could go all out and put print statements before/after every line if you want to see every step as it happens (beware the output will be extensive though so better make the text meaningful!).

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from the code what do you really aim. At least, the code differs from the task description you provided. Anyway, I'd suggest such a wild guess, for example:

*Update - I fixed the code to fit your needs, according to the working code you provided.*

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Diving_Championship
{

  class Program
  {
    private class Diver
    {
        internal Diver(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        internal readonly string Name;
        internal readonly int[] Scores = new int[5];

        internal int TotalScore
        {
            get { return Scores.OrderBy(sc => sc).Skip(1).Take(3).Sum(); }
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] diverNames = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\1 -C# Programming\Coursework\DiverName.txt");
        List<Diver> divers = new List<Diver>();

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            var diver = new Diver(diverNames[j]);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int score;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Score between 0 and 10 for {0}", diver.Name);
                    score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                } while (score < 0 || score > 10);

                diver.Scores[i] = score;
                divers.Add(diver);
            }
        }

        var MaxScore = divers.Max(d => d.TotalScore);
        var Winner = divers.First(d => d.TotalScore == MaxScore);
        Console.WriteLine("The winner is {0} with score {1}", Winner.Name, MaxScore);        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're not sure you should ask for clarification in the comments - being able to describe the problem is an important part of understanding it, and ultimately in understanding the answer somebody gives.

Comment: @Ciara, I suppose the clear code as one of the best kinds of answer in programming, often better than bunch of words.

Comment: What I meant was: instead of guessing what the OP wants why not ask them to clarify the question first.

Comment: It looks like you haven't read the original code :-), otherwise you wouldn't give such an advice. There's nothing to ask about. The task is clear enough, but the original code is far from any solution - there's nothing to discuss, the author is just starting the way of programmer (if any).

Comment: Actually I was referring to your statement "It's not completely clear from the code what do you really aim. At least, the code differs from the task description you provided. Anyway, I'd suggest such a wild guess, for example". It doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i was completely barking up the wrong tree, i have finally got my code to work, but thanks for all your input.  It's not the prettiest code but it works :P

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DivingChampionship_Coursework
{
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] divers = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\1 -C# Programming\Coursework\DiverName.txt");

        int score1 = 0;
        int score2 = 0;
        int score3 = 0;
        int score4 = 0;
        int score5 = 0;

        Diver1(ref divers, ref score1);
        Diver2(ref divers, ref score2);
        Diver3(ref divers, ref score3);
        Diver4(ref divers, ref score4);
        Diver5(ref divers, ref score5);
        FindWinner(ref divers, ref score1, ref score2, ref score3, ref score4, ref score5);
    }


    static void Diver1(ref string[] divers, ref int score1)
    {
        int[] diver1 = new int[5];
        int max1 = 0;
        int min1 = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a score for {0}", divers[0]);
            diver1[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            while (diver1[i] < 0 || diver1[i] > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opps, the score you have entered is incorrect, please enter valid score");
                diver1[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if (diver1[i] < min1)
            {
                min1 = diver1[i];
            }
            if (diver1[i] > max1)
            {
                max1 = diver1[i];
            }

        }
        score1 = diver1[0] + diver1[1] + diver1[2] + diver1[3] + diver1[4] - max1 - min1;
        Console.WriteLine("Total score is {0} from {1}", score1, divers[0]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void Diver2(ref string[] divers, ref int score2)
    {
        int[] diver2 = new int[5];
        int max2 = 0;
        int min2 = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a score for {0}", divers[1]);
            diver2[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            while (diver2[i] < 0 || diver2[i] > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opps, the score you have entered is incorrect, please enter valid score");
                diver2[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if (diver2[i] < min2)
            {
                min2 = diver2[i];
            }
            if (diver2[i] > max2)
            {
                max2 = diver2[i];
            }

        }
        score2 = diver2[0] + diver2[1] + diver2[2] + diver2[3] + diver2[4] - max2 - min2;
        Console.WriteLine("Total score is {0} from {1}", score2, divers[1]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void Diver3(ref string[] divers, ref int score3)
    {
        int[] diver3 = new int[5];
        int max3 = 0;
        int min3 = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a score for {0}", divers[2]);
            diver3[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            while (diver3[i] < 0 || diver3[i] > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opps, the score you have entered is incorrect, please enter valid score");
                diver3[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if (diver3[i] < min3)
            {
                min3 = diver3[i];
            }
            if (diver3[i] > max3)
            {
                max3 = diver3[i];
            }

        }
        score3 = diver3[0] + diver3[1] + diver3[2] + diver3[3] + diver3[4] - max3 - min3;
        Console.WriteLine("Total score is {0} from {1}", score3, divers[2]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void Diver4(ref string[] divers, ref int score4)
    {
        int[] diver4 = new int[5];
        int max4 = 0;
        int min4 = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a score for {0}", divers[3]);
            diver4[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            while (diver4[i] < 0 || diver4[i] > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opps, the score you have entered is incorrect, please enter valid score");
                diver4[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if (diver4[i] < min4)
            {
                min4 = diver4[i];
            }
            if (diver4[i] > max4)
            {
                max4 = diver4[i];
            }

        }
        score4 = diver4[0] + diver4[1] + diver4[2] + diver4[3] + diver4[4] - max4 - min4;
        Console.WriteLine("Total score is {0} from {1}", score4, divers[3]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void Diver5(ref string[] divers, ref int score5)
    {
        int[] diver5 = new int[5];
        int max5 = 0;
        int min5 = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a score for {0}", divers[4]);
            diver5[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            while (diver5[i] < 0 || diver5[i] > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opps, the score you have entered is incorrect, please enter valid score");
                diver5[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            if (diver5[i] < min5)
            {
                min5 = diver5[i];
            }
            if (diver5[i] > max5)
            {
                max5 = diver5[i];
            }

        }
        score5 = diver5[0] + diver5[1] + diver5[2] + diver5[3] + diver5[4] - max5 - min5;
        Console.WriteLine("Total score is {0} from {1}", score5, divers[4]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void FindWinner(ref string[] divers, ref int score1, ref int score2, ref int score3, ref int score4, ref int score5)
    {
        int MaximumScore = 0;
        int x = 0;

        if (score1 > MaximumScore)
        {
            MaximumScore = score1;
        }
        if (score2 > MaximumScore)
        {
            MaximumScore = score2;
            x = 1;
        }
        if (score3 > MaximumScore)
        {
            MaximumScore = score3;
            x = 2;
        }
        if (score4 > MaximumScore)
        {
            MaximumScore = score4;
            x = 3;
        }
        if (score5 > MaximumScore)
        {
            MaximumScore = score5;
            x = 4;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Max score is {0} from {1}", MaximumScore, divers[x]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Honestly saying, your code is awful (and, in general, the copy-paste approach is not the one should stick to), but I think it would be quite suspicious if you use any example provided here. :-)
Anyway, it makes sense if you have a deeper look at these examples, it advances you in programming, really.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate you've already solved your problem, but thought I'd post this short example solution:

```
Console.WriteLine("The max score is " + 
    File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\1 -C# Programming\Coursework\DiverName.txt")
    .Select(driver =>
    {
        int score;
        do Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Score between 0 and 10 for " + driver);
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out score) || score < 0 || score > 10);
        return score;
    }).Max());
```